# When I run my methods it keeps repeating itself and doesn't move on java

Tags: java, methods

Like the caption said the method "scanInput1" runs two times in a row when it should only run once. Then the method "arrayskapare" runs as intended but after that. instead of running the method "medelvarde" is jumps back and runs "scanInput1" again and again and again

```
import java.util.*;

class Heltalshanterare{
   private static String scanInput1(){
   System.out.print("Skriv in antal heltal: ");
       Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
       String antalHeltal = scr.next();

       try {
           Integer.parseInt(antalHeltal);
       }
       catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           System.out.println("Ogilitigt värde");
           scanInput1();
       }
       return antalHeltal;

   }
   private static List<Integer> arrayskapare() {
       int antalangivnatal = Integer.parseInt(scanInput1());
       int noll = 1;
       int heltal = 0;
       String tal1 = "";

       Scanner tal = new Scanner(System.in);
       List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
       while (noll <= antalangivnatal) {
           noll++;
           heltal++;
           System.out.print("ange heltal " + heltal + ": ");

           tal1 = tal.next();

           try {
               int num = Integer.parseInt(tal1);
               list.add(num);
           } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
               System.out.println("Ogiltigt värde");
               noll--;
               heltal--;
           }


       }

       return list;
   }

   public static int medelvarde(){
       int antalsiffror = arrayskapare().size();
       int sum = 0;

       for (int i : arrayskapare()){sum += i;}

       int medelvärde = sum / antalsiffror;
        System.out.println("medelvärdet av dina tal är " + medelvärde);

       return medelvarde();
   }

   public static void main(String [] args){
       scanInput1();
       arrayskapare();
       medelvarde();


   }
}
```

Im sorry that the code is so long but I have been struggling with this for too long and I really need some help.

Comment: It runs 2 times because you call it 2 times in your code. once directly in the `main` method and once inside the method `arrayskapare()` that you call from your main.

Comment: suggest not to create that many instances of `Scanner`, prefer using a single one || this kind of problem is best analyzed using a debugger ((it is running as coded if entering the correct amount of integers - but all methods are being called too often))

Answer (score 0):

Your main method is calling each method just once, which is what you need. But it's not actually holding onto any of the values being returned. So the number of heltal (integers in English) is captured from the user but then never actually stored anywhere. And later an array of numbers is captured but not stored anywhere.

Your second, bigger problem is that your methods are then calling the earlier methods all over again. So instead of asking the user to type in the data just once, you're forcing them to answer the exact same questions multiple times.

A much tidier approach is to alter your methods so that they take the required data as a parameter. Which means your `arrayskapare` (array producer) method should take the `antalHeltal` (number of integers) value as a parameter, and then it won't need to call the `scanInput1` method again. Same thing can be done for your `medelvarde` (mean value) method: have it take the array as a method parameter, so that it won't need to call `arrayskapare`.

With those changes your main method can simply look like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int antalHeltal = scanInput1();
    List<Integer> heltalArray = arrayskapare(antalHeltal);
    int medelvardet = medelvarde(heltalArray);
    System.out.println("Medelvärdet är " + medelvardet);
}
```

Now each method just gets called once and the data captured from the user gets stored into variables and passed along the river of methods until the final result is reached.